# Image appear at start of the page before the text

Tags: graphics

I am writing my thesis for high school and i need to put an image after some text, but as i do as i always did with the \begin{figure} etc. it appear at the start of the page before the text I writed before, how should I solve this?

Comment: If no optional position is specified, the placement will follow the pattern described here: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) (Potential duplicate.)

Comment: Thanks, it is really usefull

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding [hbp] after \begin {figure}. Sorry for the dumb question I'm new to LaTeX

Comment: Note that on the first page, if it doesn't fit with [h], it won't fit with [t] or [b] either.  Those options will only take place on the second page.

Comment: If you want your figure at some specific place (exactly where it is in your `tex` file), give the `[h!]` option-- which urges LaTeX to place it _here... even if it looks bad_ ! However, if you want to only exclude it from rising up, and are OK with its placement at the bottom of that page or on a separate page, `[hbp]` is fine.